# Nearest Neighbours using Quaternions

Tags: distance, quaternions, nearest-neighbor

Given a quaternion value, I would like to find its nearest neighbour in a set of quaternions. To do this, I clearly need a way to compare the "distance" between two quaternions. What distance representation is needed for such a comparison and how is it computed?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your quaternion just a point in 3D space with an orientation?

Then the distance between two quaternions `x1,y1,z1,w1` and `x2,y2,x2,w2` is given by:

`distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)`, assuming that the `w` component is used for orientation. I.e. this is the same as the distance between two 3D points.

Is your quaternion a point in 4D space?

Then the distance between them is given by:

`distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2 + (w1-w2)^2)`.

Which is just the extension to 4D space. This [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula works in any number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The quaternions are represented as a point in 4D space. I have used Euclidean distance as suggested, and it provides reasonable results.

Comment: Found an extra parenthesis in your 2nd formula there, but can't make an edit as it's less than 6 characters. Should be `distance = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2 + (w1-w2)^2)`. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but it seemed to need a little more answer.  If the quaternions are unit-length quaternions being used to represent rotations, then Euclidean distance will give some funny results because quaternions provide 2x redundant representation of rotation space; i.e., a quaternion and its negation represent the same orientation.  In this case, the correct distance metric is the angle between the quaternions, constrained to fall within `[0,pi/2]`:

```
theta = acos(q1.w*q2.w + q1.x*q2.x + q1.y*q2.y + q1.z*q2.z);
if (theta>pi/2) theta = pi - theta;
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you use your quaternions for. A simple distance measure would be the absolute value of their difference.

If
         x = a + b i + c j + d k
         y = e + f i + g j + h k

than the Euclidean distance would be

```
 |x-y| = sqrt( (a-e)² + (b-f)² + (c-g)² + (d-h)² )
```

Answer (score 0):

If "distance" you mean the shortest arc rotation between 2 orientations , than simple Euclidean distance is ok (L2 or norm2).

because angle between orientations can be written as

```
theta = acos(q1.w*q2.w + q1.x*q2.x + q1.y*q2.y + q1.z*q2.z);
```

Than, the bigger L2, the bigger distance.

NOTE: all quaternions before query should be negated if provide negative dot product. Than you can use usual KNN match to speedup your queries.