# Find nearest rotation for cube

Tags: opengl

I have camera that look at cube from above. I can rotate cube so cube can have rotation values like z=258.18594 x=1. I need advice how to get nearest rotation with cube stand on ground and camera see top face.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Quaternion mathematics and Quaternion interpolation. This will make the task rather easy.

See also [Nearest Neighbours using Quaternions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917400/nearest-neighbours-using-quaternions)